preimage attack and collision resistance of hashfunctions
I have some trouble understanding preimage resistance and collision resistance for hash functions. As definitions I use the once from wikipedia i.e.:

preimage resistance: for essentially all pre-specified outputs, it is computationally infeasible to find any input that hashes to that output


collision resistance: it is computationally infeasible to find any two distinct inputs x, x′ that hash to the same output

Now, lets assume we have a hashfunction $h:\{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{100}$ that is both - preimage resistant AND collision resistant. Now I define a new function $f:\{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{101}$ as follows
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases} 
      h(x) | 0 & |x| \not = 100 \\
      x | 1 & |x| = 100 \\
   \end{cases}
$$
where $|x|$ stands for the the length of $x$ and $m|k$ is the operator that appends $k$ to $m$.
I first claim that this function is not preimage resistant, since if we  have given an output $y$ that ends on $1$, it is easy to compute $x$ s.t. $f(x) = y$.
Further, I claim that $f$ is collision resistant, cause the only way to make $f(x) = f(x')$ is to assume that $|x| = |x'|$ (since otherwise the last bit differs). And if both have length 100, they for sure do not collide and if they have length $\not = 100$ they do not collide due to the assumption that $h$ is collision resistant.
Now, this is a contradiction to Wikipedias statement that collision resistance implies preimage resistance. Where is my mistake?

I stopped reading at your "right?". You quoted WP that preimage resistance requires the computational infeasibility for all pre-specified outputs.

yes, in the WP definition there is this second sentence where they say like: i.e., given y, it is difficult to find an x such that f(x) = y.
Here I miss this ALL-quantifier. So I wanted to make sure that others also have the same definition in mind.

I have no desire to look up that "second" WP sentence now. It should be pretty obvious that preimage resistance for only a selection of outputs is a useless definition.

Agree! Thanks for clarification. I deleted this subquestion above.

I agree with your counterexample. Maybe the claim depends on some additional assumptions, or something about "pre-specified" (what does that mean exactly?). Is there a more formal version of the claim somewhere?

You have a point here. I just found this paper. On Page 4 there is a picture where this "implication" is called a "provisional implication". I don't know what this is and have no time to read the paper in detail in the next time... But it looks like this could be the goal to answer the question :)

A function that maps $x$ to $x|1$ is anything but a hash function.

Collision resistance doesn't imply a direct pre-image resistance. It is a bit complicated, see https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/relates.pdf
